# How to delete files from Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, cloud

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and I'm having a Ubuntu One account. I synchronize a photo folder with it. Synchronizing is OK and my photo of that folder is in that cloud. The thing is now I want to delete some photos of that folder in that cloud but there is no option to delete a photo.

How do I remove some photos in the cloud?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Browse to the file.
- Click on *More* and then *Delete File* as shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: hi green7. i didn't see that area. directly i'm click to the photos tab.and inside that theres no any delete option.so thank you vary much for showing me the path.

Comment: how do I "brows" the cloud folder? when I click on "Explore" , the folder on computer opens, not the "Cloud" folder........

Answer (score 1):

you can delete them on the ubuntu one website [ubuntu one login](https://login.ubuntu.com/h16tT99ZlsWzqGl9/+decide) at there you can delete  the files and documents by cliking more one the side the last option is delete (the last one with a been sign). That easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the files from your local machine, they will also be deleted on the server; assuming the folder is still subscribed to on the machine, and thus synchronizing with the server.